# /windowApache Flink chain operators

Tags: apache-flink

I started using Apache Flink for web traffic analyze.

I didn't find a way of summarize more than 1 metric using the time window.
in the follwing example, the code aggregates usage of a word,
but what if I need to aggregate words, books, sites name etc.. (more than 1 metric on the stream)

```
val keyValuePair = wordsStream.keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.seconds(15))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to group on different attributes of your stream. For this case, you can simple replicate the stream:

```
val keyValuePair = wordsStream.keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.seconds(15))
val keyValuePair2 = wordsStream.keyBy(1).timeWindow(Time.seconds(15))
// and so forth
```

Calling multiple operation on an stream (ie, `wordsStream`) you can perform multiple computation on the same data.

Comment: thanks! is that a best practice when working with Flink? its like a spout with two bolts when comparing with Storm?

Comment: Yes, exaclty. And it is not a question of best practice -- it's the only way to do it. :)

Comment: Hi @MatthiasJ.Sax , i have noticed that when having a Tupple3 (key1,key2,count), and then aggregate them by  key0 and key1 (keyBy(x).sum(3).print()), as you mentioned (as I have understood from your answer),  the output still showed combinations such as: key0,key1,count.  Meaning: im trying to have equivalent code to this sql: select key0,count(*), and not: select key0,key1,count(*)..... Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes. Flink does not automatically projects attributes away (see "Aggregations" in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/index.html#datastream-transformations). There is also `.project(...)` available -- please read the documentation.

Comment: Sorry i have less than 10 hours experience with Flink. Your answers are really helpful

Comment: No Problem :) Just work through the documentation and examples :) Also have a look into the Flink and DataArtisans blog.